# Div not closing with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a div which I want to close with onclick.

The div has two images inside of it, the top one opens another window when clicked, and I want the bottom one to close the entire div upon clicking it. I have been playing with different onclick functions and cannot seem to close the div upon clicking the button image.

Comment: Post the code of your onlick

Comment: So we are suppose to go to the site, then grab the code and then debug it , why just not post the code here  and we can save sometime ? :)

Comment: Plus, how many times we have seen this question already?

Comment: Sorry about not posting the code. It is a third-party live chat software I was trying to integrate into my site. They do not give me the actual javascript codes so I was trying to make something on my side that would overwrite theres. The answer posted below solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if by close you mean make it disappear, simply use either one:

```
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style["visibility"] = "hidden";
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style["display"] = "none";
```

html5

```
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style["opacity"] = "0";
```

jquery

```
 $("#myDiv").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
 $("#myDiv").css({"display":"none"});
 $("#myDiv").hide();
```